# relationships produce duplicate records on query, DISTINCT does not work, any other solutions available?

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, records, ansi-sql

I am new to this portal. I have a very simple problem to be solved. It is related to the ANSI SQL. I am writing a reports using BIRT and I am fetching the data from several tables. I understand how the SQL joins work but maybe not fully. I researched google for hours and I could not find relevant answer.

My problem is that one of the relationships in the code produce a duplicate result (the same row is copied - duplicated). I was so determined to solve it I used every type of join available. Some of this SQL was produced already. I shall post my code below. I know that one of the solutions to my problem is use of the 'DISTINCT' keyword. I have used it and it does not solve my problem.

Can anyone propose any solution to that?

**Sample code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   partmaster.partdesc,
   partmaster.uom,
   traders.name AS tradername,
   worksorders.id AS worksorderno,
   worksorders.partid,
   worksorders.quantity,
   worksorders.duedate,
   worksorders.traderid,
   worksorders.orderid,
   routingoperations.partid,
   routingoperations.methodid,
   routingoperations.operationnumber,
   routingoperations.workcentreid,
   routingoperations.settime,
   routingoperations.runtime,
   routingoperations.perquantity,
   routingoperations.description,
   routingoperations.alternativeoperation,
   routingoperations.alternativeoperationpreference,
   machines.macdesc,
   machines.msection,
   allpartmaster.partnum,
   allpartmaster.nbq,
   allpartmaster.partdesc,
   routingoperationtools.toolid,
   tools.tooldesc,
   CAST (emediadetails.data as VARCHAR(MAX)) AS cplandata
FROM worksorders
INNER JOIN partmaster ON worksorders.partid = partmaster.partnum
INNER JOIN traders traders ON worksorders.traderid = traders.id
INNER JOIN routingoperations routingoperations ON worksorders.partid = routingoperations.partid  
       AND worksorders.routingmethod = routingoperations.methodid
INNER JOIN allpartmaster allpartmaster ON routingoperations.partid = allpartmaster.partnum 
LEFT OUTER JOIN machines machines ON routingoperations.workcentreid = machines.macid
LEFT OUTER JOIN routingoperationtools routingoperationtools ON routingoperationtools.partid = routingoperations.partid 
           AND routingoperationtools.routingmethod = routingoperations.methodid 
           AND routingoperationtools.operationnumber = routingoperations.operationnumber     
LEFT OUTER JOIN tools tools ON tools.toolid = routingoperationtools.toolid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN emediadetails ON emediadetails.keyvalue1 = worksorders.id 
            AND emediadetails.keyvalue2 = routingoperations.operationnumber 
            AND emediadetails.emediaid = 'worksorderoperation'
```

I do not have too much of the test data but I know that one row is copied twice as the result of the query below even tho I used `DISTINCT` keyword. I know that my problem is rather specific and not general but the solution that someone will propose may help others with the similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't solve your problem for you without some test data, but I have some helpful hints.

In principle, you should be really careful with DISTINCT - its a great way of hiding bugs in your query. Only use DISTINCT if you are confident that the underlying data contains legitimate duplicates. If your joins are wrong, and you're getting a cartesian product, you can remove the duplicates from the results with DISTINCT - but that doesn't stop the cartesian product being generated. You'll get very poor performance, and possibly incorrect data.

Secondly, I am pretty sure that DISTINCT works properly - you are almost certainly not getting duplicates, but it may be hard to spot the difference between two rows. Leading or trailing spaces in text columns, for instance could be to blame.

Finally, to work through this problem, I'd recommend building the query up join by join, and seeing where you get the duplicate - that's the join that's to blame.

So, start with:

```
SELECT 

                    traders.name AS tradername,
                    worksorders.id AS worksorderno,
                    worksorders.partid,
                    worksorders.quantity,
                    worksorders.duedate,
                    worksorders.traderid,
                    worksorders.orderid
                FROM worksorders
                    INNER JOIN traders traders ON
                        worksorders.traderid = traders.id
```

and build up to the next join.

Comment: Ta very much for that. For the databases wherever I design a simple report or the complex query I always tend to research the structures of the tables and draw up ERD's to have a clear reference. I have seen someone using 'group by' command to skip the duplicates instead of the 'distinct' is that possible?

Comment: I've seen your response to Johann Strydom - if you have extra content in the emediadetails.data, it suggests that table has two rows which match the join criteria. Is there a way of refining that join to specify which row you want to retrieve? The crudest way would be to add "and Cplandata not like '%<br>', but hopefully there's a better way. The way to do this with "group by" is to select for instance the max(keyvalue1) and then grouping by all the other columns. Only do this if the data in that table is legitimately duplicated, and the first record is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the results are exact duplicates?  Makes sure there isn't one column that actually has a different value.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! I am really sorry. There is only one difference: for the field - CAST (emediadetails.data as VARCHAR(MAX)) AS cplandata the data consists <br> tag in one row where it does not in another. Question is that these rows are virtually the same. I just need to exclude the repetition of this row. Even if the values are different I just need to omit this field if other fields are the same. Can I use 'group by' to omit one of the results?

Comment: @techspeque: You said, "these rows are virtually the same." You undoubtedly meant to say, "These rows are different", because they're different. As long as the values in the columns you select are different, they will be, ummm, different. If you want to make them the same--which sounds like a really bad idea--either drop that column from your query, or copy the data so it's identical in both rows. (Again, that sounds like a really bad idea.)

Comment: @Catcall, I know I said they are the same. The problem was that the data was the HTML code. And in the length of the 1200 characters in the middle the <br> tag was added and I could not spot it. Also when I previewed the data it showed as the formatted HTML page and it was not so easy. Thank you very much for your effort.